# redux state doesnt change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have setup the redux store but when I try to make changes to the state using mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps I get always the default state. So at account.js I want to get the selected language and then add it to the redux store. I try to call it in other components but I always end up with reducers/Language.js defaultState. What I'm doing wrong?

Account.js

```
class Account extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {};

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                language: {
                    sq: true,
                    en: false,
                    selected: '',
                },
            };
        }

        changeLanguage = (selected) => {
            if (this.state.sq) {
                this.setState({ selected: 'sq' });
            } else {
                this.setState({ selected: 'en' });
            }
        };


        render() {
            const navigation = this.props.navigation;
            return (
                <ScrollView>
                <View>
                        <ThemeProvider>
                            <TableView header={I18n.t('account.lang_label')}>
                                <CheckboxRow
                                    selected={this.state.language.sq}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        this.setState(state => ({
                                            language: {
                                                sq: !state.language.sq,
                                                en: !state.language.en,
                                            },
                                        }));
                                        this.changeLanguage();
                                    }}
                                    title={I18n.t('account.albanian')}
                                />
                                <CheckboxRow
                                    selected={this.state.language.en}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                        this.setState(state => ({
                                            language: {
                                                en: !state.language.en,
                                                sq: !state.language.sq,
                                            },
                                        }))
                                    }
                                    title={I18n.t('account.english')}
                                />
                            </TableView>
                        </ThemeProvider>
                    </View>
                                </ScrollView>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            changeLanguage: (selected) => { dispatch(changeLanguageEn(selected))},
        };
    };

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            language: state.language.selected,

        };
    };

    export default withNavigation(connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(Account));
```

actions/Language.js

```
import {CHANGE_LANGUAGE_EN, CHANGE_LANGUAGE_AL} from "./types";

export const changeLanguageEn = (language) => {
    return {
        type: CHANGE_LANGUAGE_EN,
        lang: language,
    }
};

export const changeLanguageAl = (language) => {
    return {
        type: CHANGE_LANGUAGE_AL,
        lang: language,
    }
};
```

reducers/Language.js

```
const defaultState = {
    lang: '',
};

export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE_EN':
           return {...state, lang: 'en'};
        case 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE_AL':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                lang: 'sq',
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: you get default state, that means you get `lang:''` ?

Comment: @McRist yeah that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you're trying to update the redux state with the internal state of `Account`? You should be able to do:

`this.props.changeLanguage(this.state.language.selected)`

You have a method on your component defined `changeLanguage` as well, perhaps you could do the line above in that method, after changing the internal state

additionally, in your changeLanguage method in your `Account` class, I don't think `this.state.sq` exists since sq is a key in the `language` state object. Instead it should be `this.state.language.sq`. You don't need to add the selected argument to this method either. Try making your changeLanguage method to look like this

```
changeLanguage = () => {
    if (this.state.sq) {
        this.setState({ language.selected: 'sq' });
    } else {
        this.setState({ language.selected: 'en' });
    }
   // dispatch your action here after updating the state
  this.props.changeLanguage(this.state.language.selected)
};
```

Now calling `this.changeLanguage();` will update your internal state, and then dispatch your changeLanguage redux action

Answer (score 2):

In your `mapStateToProps` function try with `state.lang` directly

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        language: state.lang,
    };
};
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the selected language incorrectly. `state.language.selected`.

In the reducer you are adding `lang` property in the state, so access it with the same property name in the mapStateToProps.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        language: state.language.lang,
    };
};
```

Comment: but how I add the selected value to the lang property ?

Comment: you have added it in the reducer. and used it in mapStateToProps as  `language: state.language.lang` , now you can access this as props in the component as -> `this.props.language`

Comment: thank you but I was saying, how can I pass this.state.selected value  to the reducers lang prop

Comment: you have already passed it to the action, but in the reducer you are always returning `lang:'en'`, to return the selected language, you should have done : 

`return {...state, lang: action.lang};`

Comment: I changed this `const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        language: state.language.lang,
    };
}`

Comment: `export const changeLanguageEn = (language) => {
    return {
        type: CHANGE_LANGUAGE,
        lang: language,
    }
};`

Comment: `export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE':
            return {...state, lang: action.lang};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}`

Comment: and still I get the same default value

Comment: where are you checking that you are getting the default value? ...  what are you getting on `console.log(state)` before `return` statement in `mapStateToProps function`

Comment: I'm testing using console log and I get only ' ' which is the default state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178666/discussion-between-anxd-and-mcrist).